# Galera Cluster Rancher Node Scaling Issue

Tags: docker, mariadb, galera, rancher

I have a very specific issue. I am using Rancher to manage my docker containers and am using the Galera Cluster Community Template. I added a second host to my setup and if I am scaling the clusting now - it keeps saying

> level=fatal msg="invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value"

I can not really trace the error, nor do I have an idea where to look.

My research so far - it might be connected to the host communication protocolls (http vs https) since other people have had this error.

My question - how can I trace / debug and fix this error?

```
Additional information:
Docker Version on both hosts: 1.12.5
Rancher Version: v1.1.4
```

If you need anything else - I will be happy to provide more information.

Comment: If you are putting all the Galera nodes on the same server, please explain what you hope to gain.

Comment: Hello Rick, thanks for the interest. I wanted to scale the nodes of the cluster on both hosts. My hope is to gain speed (reduce workload on the main system). Scaling to two hosts should be easy - but I can not figure out where there error is.

Comment: Two Galera Nodes on same physical server:  You gain nothing in I/O, possibly lose something because of having smaller caches and redundant I/O.  Plus every write now has to be written twice on the same physical server, thereby increasing the I/O load.

Comment: Hello Rick, I think you got me wrong - I have **two** physical servers and want to distribute the nodes to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this one out. It actually is not a problem with the template or Galera Cluster itself.
The issue is within the way rancher / docker is fetching the IP within the evironment. The cause is that ubuntu ships by default using dns server as local address 127.0.0.1 and is by design. Problem is docker containers can't lookup in 127.0.0.1.

See your **/etc/resolv.conf** file

Perform a test:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
apt update
apt install dnsutils
# This will not respond
dig @127.0.0.1 your.hostname.com
```

Note: ping WILL work fine, and could trick you in thinking that name resolution is working. Dig is a proper way of doing that.

You can also use rancher cli to get a hint of the problem:

```
mkdir -p support
rancher hosts -a > support/hosts
rancher logs --tail=-1 ipsec/ipsec > support/ipsec 2>&1
rancher logs --tail=-1 network-services/metadata > support/metadata 2>&1
rancher logs --tail=-1 network-services/network-manager > support/network-manager 2>&1
```

**Solution:**

There are two solutions:

1 - Configure ubuntu to use other nameserver like google public dns (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4). I try this one, and is by far too complicated for a simple change, as a said, ubuntu use that by design.

2 - Change docker dns server. This worked fine for me. You will edit or create the file /etc/docker/daemon.json and put the line:

```
{
  "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]
}
```

Stop the containers and Restart the daemon:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
docker stop $(docker ps -q) # yes twice :-) rancher will try do restart your dying containers
systemctl restart docker
```

Big thanks to [Giovanni](https://github.com/giovannicandido)